# Admin Block Form Edit File Than The Choose File Was blank and re upload the file at edit time?

Tags: magento2, blocks, adminform

> Here is my form admin edit

[image]

> See here choose file was blank when we edit the image
>
> here is my edit file code
>
> Controller\Adminhtml\banner\Edit.php

```
<?php

namespace Vrinsoft\Banner\Controller\Adminhtml\banner;

use Magento\Backend\App\Action;

class Edit extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
{
    /**
     * Core registry
     *
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Registry
     */
    protected $_coreRegistry = null;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory
     */
    protected $resultPageFactory;

    /**
     * @param Action\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry
     */
    public function __construct(
        Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry
    ) {
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
        $this->_coreRegistry = $registry;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    protected function _isAllowed()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Init actions
     *
     * @return \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Page
     */
    protected function _initAction()
    {
        // load layout, set active menu and breadcrumbs
        /** @var \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Page $resultPage */
        $resultPage = $this->resultPageFactory->create();
        $resultPage->setActiveMenu('Vrinsoft_Banner::Banner')
            ->addBreadcrumb(__('Vrinsoft Banner'), __('Vrinsoft Banner'))
            ->addBreadcrumb(__('Manage Item'), __('Manage Item'));
        return $resultPage;
    }

    /**
     * Edit Item
     *
     * @return \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Page|\Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Redirect
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.NPathComplexity)
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        // 1. Get ID and create model
        $id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
        $model = $this->_objectManager->create('Vrinsoft\Banner\Model\Banner');

        // 2. Initial checking
        if ($id) {
            $model->load($id);
            if (!$model->getId()) {
                $this->messageManager->addError(__('This item no longer exists.'));
                /** \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Redirect $resultRedirect */
                $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();

                return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/');
            }
        }

        // 3. Set entered data if was error when we do save
        $data = $this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Backend\Model\Session')->getFormData(true);
        if (!empty($data)) {
            $model->setData($data);
        }

        // 4. Register model to use later in blocks
        $this->_coreRegistry->register('banner', $model);

        // 5. Build edit form
        /** @var \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Page $resultPage */
        $resultPage = $this->_initAction();
        $resultPage->setActiveMenu('Vrinsoft_Banner::banner');
        $resultPage->addBreadcrumb(__('Vrinsoft'), __('Vrinsoft'));
        $resultPage->addBreadcrumb(
            $id ? __('Edit Layer Data') : __('New Layer Data'),
            $id ? __('Edit Layer Data') : __('New Layer Data')
        );
        $resultPage->getConfig()->getTitle()->prepend($id ? __('Edit Layer Data') : __('New Layer Data'));
        //$resultPage->getConfig()->getTitle()->prepend($model->getId() ? $model->getTitle() : __('New Item'));

        return $resultPage;
    }
}
```

> Here is my save.php code
>
> Controller\Adminhtml\banner\Save.php

```
<?php
namespace Vrinsoft\Banner\Controller\Adminhtml\banner;

use Magento\Backend\App\Action;
use Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList;


class Save extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
{
    public function __construct(Action\Context $context)
    {
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        $data = $this->getRequest()->getPostValue();

        // echo $data1 = $_FILES['banner']['name'];
        // echo $data2 = $_FILES['full_image']['name'];
       


        
        /** @var \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Redirect $resultRedirect */
        $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
        if ($data) {
            $model = $this->_objectManager->create('Vrinsoft\Banner\Model\Banner');

            $id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
            if ($id) {
                $model->load($id);
                $model->setCreatedAt(date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
            }
            
            try{
                if($_FILES['banner']['name'])
                {
                    
                    $uploader = $this->_objectManager->create('Magento\MediaStorage\Model\File\Uploader',['fileId' => 'banner'] );
                    $uploader->setAllowedExtensions(['jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif', 'png']);
                    /** @var \Magento\Framework\Image\Adapter\AdapterInterface $imageAdapter */
                    $imageAdapter = $this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Image\AdapterFactory')->create();
                    $uploader->setAllowRenameFiles(true);
                    $uploader->setFilesDispersion(true);

                    /** @var \Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Directory\Read $mediaDirectory */
                    $mediaDirectory = $this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Filesystem')
                        ->getDirectoryRead(DirectoryList::MEDIA);


                    $result = $uploader->save($mediaDirectory->getAbsolutePath('banner_banner'));
                    if($result['error']==0)
                        {
                            // echo "string";
                            // exit;
                            $data['banner'] = 'banner_banner' . $result['file'];                        
                        }
                }    
                if($_FILES['full_image']['name'])
                {        
                    
                    $uploader1 = $this->_objectManager->create('Magento\MediaStorage\Model\File\Uploader',['fileId' => 'full_image'] );
                    $uploader1->setAllowedExtensions(['jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif', 'png']);
                    /** @var \Magento\Framework\Image\Adapter\AdapterInterface $imageAdapter */
                    $imageAdapter = $this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Image\AdapterFactory')->create();
                    $uploader1->setAllowRenameFiles(true);
                    $uploader1->setFilesDispersion(true);

                     /** @var \Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Directory\Read $mediaDirectory */
                    $mediaDirectory = $this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Filesystem')
                        ->getDirectoryRead(DirectoryList::MEDIA);
                    
                    // print_r($result);
                    // exit;
                    $result1 = $uploader1->save($mediaDirectory->getAbsolutePath('banner_banner'));
                        
                        if($result1['error']==0)
                        {
                            $data['full_image'] = 'banner_banner' . $result1['file'];
                        }
                }    


            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                //unset($data['image']);
            }
            
            if(isset($data['banner']['delete']) && $data['banner']['delete'] == '1')
                $data['banner'] = '';

           

            if(isset($data['store_id']) && $data['store_id']){
                $data['store_id'] = implode(',',$data['store_id']);
            }
            
            $model->setData($data);

            try {
                $model->save();
                $this->messageManager->addSuccess(__('The Banner has been saved.'));
                $this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Backend\Model\Session')->setFormData(false);
                if ($this->getRequest()->getParam('back')) {
                    return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/edit', ['id' => $model->getId(), '_current' => true]);
                }
                return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/');
            } catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException $e) {
                $this->messageManager->addError($e->getMessage());
            } catch (\RuntimeException $e) {
                $this->messageManager->addError($e->getMessage());
            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                echo $e->getMessage();die;
                $this->messageManager->addException($e, __('Something went wrong while saving the Banner.'));
            }

            $this->_getSession()->setFormData($data);
            return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/edit', ['id' => $this->getRequest()->getParam('id')]);
        }
        return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/');
    }
}
```

> Block\Adminhtml\Banner\Edit\Tab\Main.php

```
<?php

namespace Vrinsoft\Banner\Block\Adminhtml\Banner\Edit\Tab;

/**
 * Banner edit form main tab
 */
class Main extends \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Form\Generic implements \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Tab\TabInterface
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Store\Model\System\Store
     */
    protected $_systemStore;

    /**
     * @var \Vrinsoft\Banner\Model\Status
     */
    protected $_status;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Data\FormFactory $formFactory
     * @param \Magento\Store\Model\System\Store $systemStore
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        \Magento\Framework\Data\FormFactory $formFactory,
        \Magento\Store\Model\System\Store $systemStore,
        \Vrinsoft\Banner\Model\Status $status,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->_systemStore = $systemStore;
        $this->_status = $status;
        parent::__construct($context, $registry, $formFactory, $data);
    }

    /**
     * Prepare form
     *
     * @return $this
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.ExcessiveMethodLength)
     */
    protected function _prepareForm()
    {
    
      $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance(); // Instance of object manager
      $resource = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection');
      $connection = $resource->getConnection();
      $tableName = $resource->getTableName('screen_layer_data'); //gives table name with prefix

      // $sql_cat    = "Select category_id,category_name From " . $tableName . " GROUP BY category_id ";
      // $result_cat = $connection->fetchAll($sql_cat);

      // foreach ($result_cat as $data_cat)
      // {
      //    $layer_cat[$data_cat['category_id']]=$data_cat['category_name'];
      // }

      // echo "</pre>";
      // print_r($layer_cat);
      

      
        /* @var $model \Vrinsoft\Banner\Model\BlogPosts */
        $model = $this->_coreRegistry->registry('banner');

        $isElementDisabled = false;

        /** @var \Magento\Framework\Data\Form $form */
        $form = $this->_formFactory->create();

        $form->setHtmlIdPrefix('page_');

        $fieldset = $form->addFieldset('base_fieldset', ['legend' => __('Layer Data Information')]);

        if ($model->getId()) {
            $fieldset->addField('id', 'hidden', ['name' => 'id']);
        }

        // $fieldset->addField(
        //     'category',
        //     'select',
        //     [
        //         'name' => 'category',
        //         'label' => __('Category'),
        //         'title' => __('Category'),
        //         'required' => false,
        //         'values'=> $layer_cat,
        //         'disabled' => $isElementDisabled
        //     ]
        // );


      $sql = "Select * FROM " . $tableName ;
      $result = $connection->fetchAll($sql);


      foreach($result as $data) 
      {
        $layer_category_name = $data['category_name'] ." ".$data['layer_name']; 
        $layer_data[$data['layer_id']]=$layer_category_name;
      }


        $fieldset->addField(
            'layer_id',
            'select',
            [
                'name' => 'layer_id',
                'label' => __('Layer Id'),
                'title' => __('Layer Id'),
                'required' => false,
                'values'=> $layer_data,
                'disabled' => $isElementDisabled
            ]
        );

        // $fieldset->addField(
  //           'layer_id',
  //           'text',
  //           [
  //               'name' => 'layer_id',
  //               'label' => __('Layer Id'),
  //               'title' => __('Layer Id'),
  //               'required' => false,
  //               'disabled' => $isElementDisabled
  //           ]
  //       );

        $fieldset->addField(
            'banner',
            'image',
            [
                'name' => 'banner',
                'label' => __('Banner'),
                'title' => __('Banner'),
                'required' => true,
                'disabled' => $isElementDisabled
            ]
        );

         $fieldset->addField(
            'full_image',
            'image',
            [
                'name' => 'full_image',
                'label' => __('Full Image'),
                'title' => __('Full Image'),
                'required' => true,
                'disabled' => $isElementDisabled
            ]
        );
                
    //     $fieldset->addField(
    //         'title',
    //         'text',
    //         [
    //             'name' => 'title',
    //             'label' => __('Title'),
    //             'title' => __('Title'),
                // 'required' => true,
    //             'disabled' => $isElementDisabled
    //         ]
    //     );

        // $fieldset->addField(
        //     'store_id',
        //     'multiselect',
        //     [
        //         'name' => 'store_id[]',
        //         'label' => __('Store View'),
        //         'title' => __('Store View'),
        //         'required' => true,
        //         'values' => $this->_systemStore->getStoreValuesForForm(false, true)
        //     ]
        // );
         $fieldset->addField(
            'category_id',
            'text',
            [
                'name' => 'category_id',
                'label' => __('Category Id'),
                'title' => __('Category Id'),
                'required' => false,
                'disabled' => $isElementDisabled
            ]
        );
                

        $fieldset->addField(
            'product_id',
            'text',
            [
                'name' => 'product_id',
                'label' => __('Product Id'),
                'title' => __('Product Id'),
                'required' => false,
                'disabled' => $isElementDisabled
            ]
        );

        $fieldset->addField(
            'text_description',
            'text',
            [
                'name' => 'text_description',
                'label' => __('Text Description'),
                'title' => __('Text Description'),
                'required' => false,
                'disabled' => $isElementDisabled
            ]
        );

        

        $fieldset->addField(
            'select_date',
            'date',
            [
                'name' => 'select_date',
                'label' => __('Select Date'),
                'title' => __('Select Date'),
                'required' => false,
                'disabled' => $isElementDisabled,
                'singleClick'=> true,
                'date_format' => 'yyyy-MM-dd',
                'time_format' => 'hh:mm:ss',
                'time'=>true
            ]
        );

        // $fieldset->addField(
        //     'time',
        //     'date',
        //     [
        //         'name' => 'time',
        //         'label' => __('Time'),
        //         'title' => __('Time'), 
        //         'disabled' => $isElementDisabled,
        //         'singleClick'=> true,
        //         'date_format' => 'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss',
        //         'time'=>true
        //     ]
        // );


        $fieldset->addField(
            'status',
            'select',
            [
                'name' => 'status',
                'label' => __('Status'),
                'title' => __('Status'),
                'required' => false,
                'values'=> array(1=>'Enable', 2=>'Desable'),
                'disabled' => $isElementDisabled
            ]
        );

        

        

       
                        

        if (!$model->getId()) {
            $model->setData('is_active', $isElementDisabled ? '0' : '1');
        }
        $data = $model->getData();

        if(isset($data['layer_id']) && $data['layer_id']){
            $data['layer_id'] = explode(',',$data['layer_id']);
        }

        $form->setValues($model->getData());
        $this->setForm($form);

        return parent::_prepareForm();
    }

    public function getTabLabel()
    {
        return __('Layer Data Information');
    }

    public function getTabTitle()
    {
        return __('Layer Data Information');
    }

    public function canShowTab()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public function isHidden()
    {
        return false;
    }

    protected function _isAllowedAction($resourceId)
    {
        return $this->_authorization->isAllowed($resourceId);
    }

    public function getTargetOptionArray(){
        return array(
                    '_self' => "Self",
                    '_blank' => "New Page",
                    );
    }
}
```

> what problem in that each and every time when we edit time re upload
> the image data